# Double emulator

Tags: xbox-360

I'm looking to install a PS3 OS on my XBOX360 so I can play both emulators. But mainly so I can use the PS3 to get online and play games without a subscription.

Is this possible and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: What about vice versa putting a 360 os on a ps3

Comment: Again, no. For the exact same reasons except with the names swapped.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is **no**, for a number of reasons - I've listed a few here but this is just the tip of the iceberg, really.

**You can't emulate current consoles on current consoles**

There's a general rule of thumb that in order to fully emulate a console or other system you need a device that is several times more powerful than the emulated system. This is partly due to the complexity of completely emulating an entire hardware system at a software level (essentially recreating the hardware logic gate by gate).

**Even if you don't mean emulation, the hardware is totally different**

The PS3 OS is designed for the PS3 and the PS3 *only*. The architecture difference between it and the X360 is enormous and I highly doubt the OS even *could* run on the X360 without extensive changes.

**The OS is proprietary and not available**

There's no real way to get a copy of the PS3 OS (other than buying a PS3 of course, but that's no use in this case as you would need the source code or magically compiled binaries that magically run on the X360).

**It would violate the X360 Terms of Agreement**

This would definitely count as modding as your X360 and as such is not allowed under the licence that Microsoft provides. This may not be an issue for you personally but you should be aware of the implications. Of course, this is the least of your concerns as for this to be an issue you'd have to manage to get the thing done in the first place.

Comment: Also, even *if* you got it to work, it wouldn't be able to run XB360 games anymore...

Comment: @Shadur Eh, dunno. If the X360 doesn't mind partitioned HDDs (it might think it's a sign of modding, but I have no info on this) then it shouldn't matter what is on the other partitions, working or not. Not enough info either way, though...

Comment: @Alex - Considering the operating system isn't even installed on the HDD for the XBOX 360 I would argue the fact it supports partitioned HDDs is not important.  The underline operating system is stored in memory we as users don't have access to.

Comment: @Ramhound good point, I forgot about that. But the PS3 OS would have to be on some sort of partition anyway unless it was to completely replace the X360 OS. Then we need a supersmart bootloader to deal with all this...Far far far quicker and easier to buy a PS3 :)